# Get context of RequestHandler object from another class

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a Utility class method I want to utilize from other App Engine Python classes:

```
def parse_query_string_paramter(self, paramter, default=None):

        if self.request.get(paramter):

            # ...
```

I am unsure of how to pass the context of the original request when calling this method from another class as below:

```
import webapp2
from utilities import Utility


class Search(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):

        utility = Utility()
        search_query = utility.parse_query_string_paramter('q')
        # ...
```

The error returned below makes sense to me, the Pythonic solution though I'm unclear where to start:

```
File "~/utilities.py", line 112, in parse_query_string_paramter
    if self.request.get(paramter):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

**Update:**

Thanks to Tim's solution, the updated code below is now working for me:

```
def parse_query_string_paramter(self, context, paramter, default=None):

        if context.request.get(paramter):

            # ...
```

and passing `self` from the calling class as below:

```
search_query = utility.parse_query_string_paramter(self, 'q')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to pass request from the handler `Search` as an argument to the Utility class on instantiation or as an argument of the `parse_query_string_paramter` method, it can't magically get the request object.

As an aside it is not clear why you would have a Utility class unless some sort of state is being held by an instance of Utility for the duration of the request, when you may only need a function.

Comment: Thanks Tim, passing as an argument did the trick. I'd been using the Utility class to hold common methods used in a few classes, rather than have to declare them in each class. I can see from your comment how that could be wasteful to instantiate the class for each request though, I need to and will invest in some software design education.

Comment: JUst define the methods as functions in the utility module. Then just use `utilities.parse_query_string_paramter`  Remember python does force you to use object/classes for every situation.

Comment: Thannks again Tim, I'm now refactoring to use inheritence vs the utility class which was adding unnecessary complexity to the management of the app.